# unable to checkout foreign repository in git action

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to checkout a foreign repo in my github action. Here is a snippet of my yaml file

```yaml
name: Check Set-Up & Build

# Controls when the action will run.
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  check:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - name: Download Substrate Template
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template
          path: substrate-node-template
```

I am using [act](https://github.com/nektos/act) for local testing. When I run it , i.e. `act`. I get the follow error, it seems like the repository files and paths are being ignored.

```bash
[Check Set-Up & Build/check] ⭐  Run Download Substrate Template
[Check Set-Up & Build/check]   ❌  Failure - Download Substrate Template
[Check Set-Up & Build/check] Expected format {org}/{repo}[/path]@ref. Actual '' Input string was not in a correct format.
Error: Job 'check' failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That was an easy fix. You need to add `ref` parameter to your action as well. It should ideally look like this:

```yaml
- name: Download Substrate Template
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
      repository: substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template
      ref: main
      path: substrate-node-template
```

Though this doesn't work with `act`, it does work on GHA:

[image]